# the breakpoint will not be hit, the source code is different than the original version - VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, break

VS 2008 is randomly giving me an error after working on a project for weeks. When I set a debug point, I get a warning: The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.
I have tried different things
1. Deleted the .suo file
2. Tried devenv /ResetSettings 
3. deleted the temp files from Windows/Microsoft.net/framework/v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files/

Does anyone has any idea how to fix this?

While debugging I get this in my Modules window

```
 mscorlib.dll    Skipped loading symbols.  70B60000-71658000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll      
 System.Web.dll  Skipped loading symbols.  6D3F0000-6DF36000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll  
 System.dll      Skipped loading symbols.  703C0000-70B59000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll        
 System.Configuration.dll Skipped loading symbols.  701D0000-702C1000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll
 System.Xml.dll  Skipped loading symbols.  6FC90000-701C6000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll
 System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll Skipped loading symbols.  508F0000-50926000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll
 Microsoft.JScript.dll Skipped loading symbols.  5D700000-5D93D000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll
 CppCodeProvider.dll Skipped loading symbols.  44C10000-44C2C000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CppCodeProvider\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\CppCodeProvider.dll
 System.Data.dll Skipped loading symbols.  6C2E0000-6C933000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
 System.Web.Services.dll Skipped loading symbols.  51DA0000-51F65000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll
 System.Drawing.dll Skipped loading symbols.  5F040000-5F1C7000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll
 System.EnterpriseServices.dll Skipped loading symbols.  6B430000-6B4CD000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll
 System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll Skipped loading symbols.  03E20000-03E68000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
 System.Web.Mobile.dll Skipped loading symbols.  77B10000-77D2F000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll
 DundasWebChart.DLL Skipped loading symbols.  11000000-1106E000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\iep_31_base\d311e736\8bee08e7\assembly\dl3\d9d476fd\00ba2da1_9469c201\DundasWebChart.DLL
 IEP_31_Base.DLL Symbols loaded.           02990000-02FC0000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\iep_31_base\d311e736\8bee08e7\assembly\dl3\c47ce5b2\9cd8c9b4_ca85cb01\IEP_31_Base.DLL
 NetchemiaFoundationClasses.DLL Skipped loading symbols.  02000000-0207C000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\iep_31_base\d311e736\8bee08e7\assembly\dl3\f3cbc113\035f09b7_5066cb01\NetchemiaFoundationClasses.DLL
 NetchemiaFoundations.DLL Skipped loading symbols.  030C0000-03174000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\iep_31_base\d311e736\8bee08e7\assembly\dl3\dbd1286a\eef01e76_d07acb01\NetchemiaFoundations.DLL
 netIEPManagementClasses.DLL Skipped loading symbols.  01130000-01148000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\iep_31_base\d311e736\8bee08e7\assembly\dl3\254fc8c5\1ada8ebe_5066cb01\netIEPManagementClasses.DLL
 System.Runtime.Serialization.dll Skipped loading symbols.  6E070000-6E2B1000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
 System.IdentityModel.dll Skipped loading symbols.  6E2D0000-6E3D9000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll
 System.ServiceModel.dll Skipped loading symbols.  6E4E0000-6F57C000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll
 System.ServiceModel.Web.dll Skipped loading symbols.  6D0F0000-6D293000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
 System.WorkflowServices.dll Skipped loading symbols.  6D2A0000-6D3F0000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll
 System.Core.dll Skipped loading symbols.  51880000-51AB4000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll
 System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll Skipped loading symbols.  02080000-020A5000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
 System.Web.Extensions.dll Skipped loading symbols.  6CD20000-6CF6E000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll
 System.Web.Abstractions.dll Skipped loading symbols.  50460000-50486000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Abstractions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Abstractions.dll
 System.Xml.Linq.dll Skipped loading symbols.  77AA0000-77B06000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll
 A_495e38af_86f6_4a92_91e6_eee0640b999b No symbols loaded.        00000000-00000000   A_495e38af_86f6_4a92_91e6_eee0640b999b                                          
 M_495e38af_86f6_4a92_91e6_eee0640b999b No symbols loaded.        00000000-00000000   M_495e38af_86f6_4a92_91e6_eee0640b999b                                          
 App_global.asax.7p2wok51.dll Symbols loaded.           03030000-0303A000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\iep_31_base\d311e736\8bee08e7\App_global.asax.7p2wok51.dll
 Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll Skipped loading symbols.  51080000-5121B000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
```

>

Comment: Are you using attach to process to debug?

Comment: Do a Clean Solution, then Build Solution to clear out any stale PDBs and DLLs.

Comment: @ryudice - yes, I am using the "attach to process" to attach the w3wp.exe

Comment: @Oded - I tried that...did not help.Also FYI..I am running VS 2008 on Windows 7 Machine

Answer (score 0):

stop the debugger
close the IDE
close the hosting application
Restart Vs using command devenv /resetsettings
rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

The resetsettings didn't work for me so shutdown visual studio and went into the project that contained the file and deleted the bin and obj directories.